# data from firebase not mapped react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i have data from firebase and i want map it to my custom panels but it seems not mapped (my panels do not show up) but when i console log it, the data succesfully retreived. here is my code

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            requests:[]
        }
      }
      
      componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchRequests();
      }
      
      fetchRequests(){
        this.subscriber = firebase.firestore()
        .collection("requests").onSnapshot(docs => {
            let requests = []
            docs.forEach(doc => {
              requests.push(doc.data())
            })
            this.setState({requests})
        })
    }
    
    buildPanels() { 
        this.state.requests.map((req, idx) => {
          return <View key={idx} style={styles.panel}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <View style={styles.panelRow}>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>Nama Resipien</Text>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>{req.name}</Text>  
              </View>
              <View style={styles.panelRow}>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>Golongan Darah</Text>
                <Text style={{flex: 0.5}}>{req.golDarah}</Text>  
              </View>
          </View>
      </View>
        })
        
        render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                      <ScrollView>
                        {this.buildPanels()}
                      </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return` method in your code like

```
buildPanels() { 
        return this.state.requests.map((req, idx) => {
          return <View key={idx} style={styles.panel}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <View style={styles.panelRow}>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>Nama Resipien</Text>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>{req.name}</Text>  
              </View>
              <View style={styles.panelRow}>
                <Text style={styles.panelText}>Golongan Darah</Text>
                <Text style={{flex: 0.5}}>{req.golDarah}</Text>  
              </View>
          </View>
      </View>
})
```